# Haskell calling a file has input

Tags: haskell

Imagine that I have compiled the file program.hs where:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do a <- getArgs 
          w <- getContents
...
```

My question is how can I run that program in the windows command line such that it receives input from file.txt?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, because your program doesn't receive input from any files, only the command line arguments, and Windows doesn't give you a way to copy a file to the command line arguments (besides manual copy-paste).

Comment: Hi, i think you're right, Image now this code if you can:
main = do a <- getArgs


          w <- getContents

In there, a will be the args in the command line right?(ex: :main a b) 
And w will came from the studin right?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<` input redirection operator when running the program:

```
program otherargumentsgohere < inputfile.txt
```

Comment: It runs, but the program is not giving back what i want... But i think i may have something wrong in the .txt file I'm using, thank you...